# How to check if Media Foundation can actually play a file and not just load it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I'm having some problems with MPEG1 videos and Media Foundation: So Media Foundation doesn't support playback of MPEG1 video streams ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supported-media-formats-in-media-foundation)), but for some reason it will still open them and it will even report the correct duration and frame size. So at opening time everything looks like it can play those files.

But it can't! Once you try to actually play the MPEG1 video file, `IMFAsyncCallback::Invoke()` will be called with a status of `MESessionTopologySet` and then `IMFMediaEvent::GetStatus()` will return 0xc004f011 and that's about it.

So is there any way to check if a video format can actually be played by Media Foundation *after opening it* or is there any way to make Media Foundation only open files that it can actually play? Currently I can only tell if a file can be played or not by attempting to start playback and then see if it works or not which is somewhat inconvenient. I'd like to be able to tell if a file can be played or not much earlier.

Comment: Does building topology and pausing works for you to solve the raised task? I believe pausing can't succeed in the `SL_E_LICENSE_FILE_NOT_INSTALLED` situation.

Comment: @RomanR.: Sorry, doesn't help. `IMFMediaSession::Pause` returns 0, i.e. success, on MPEG1 files.

Comment: Then probably next good option using standard components is to build a playback topology(with decoding!) to [samplegrabber sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/using-the-sample-grabber-sink). It has to fail on playback then.

Comment: @RomanR.: But won't this also fail on DRM protected content then? AFAIR not all codecs allow sample grabbing...

Comment: Do you play MPEG1 DRM-enabled content via Media Foundation? The point is valid overall... but this combination of factors look weird to be. Then you don't need to even access the played samples: important is that samples reach sink in first place.

Comment: One another thought is that you can probe system with your own content file which you know is not DRM-enabled. So you would rule out DRM aspect. Also I believe that failure to decrypt DRM content would result in a different error code (I actually think that you won't even be able to play DRM content in Media Session in first place - you would have to use PMP and even then you'd have lots of troubles)

Comment: @RomanR.: Thanks. For simplicity's sake I've done some experiments with `IMFSourceReader` instead of the sample grabber. This seems to do the trick. See below, I've posted an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this now by using `IMFSourceReader`. I have found out that trying to set the media type to `MFVideoFormat_RGB32` will fail with MPEG1 video streams but it will work fine with MPEG4 so this is probably a feasible way to check if Media Foundation can actually play a file. In code, the solution looks like this:

```
hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttr, 1);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            
    IMFAttributes_SetUINT32(pAttr, &MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, TRUE);
    IMFAttributes_SetUINT32(pAttr, &MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_VIDEO_PROCESSING, TRUE);

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(filename, pAttr, &pReader);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            
        hr = IMFSourceReader_GetCurrentMediaType(pReader, MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &pFileVideoMediaType);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                        
            hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pTypeUncomp);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                        
                IMFMediaType_CopyAllItems(pFileVideoMediaType, (IMFAttributes *) pTypeUncomp);

                IMFMediaType_SetGUID(pTypeUncomp, &MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
                IMFMediaType_SetUINT32(pTypeUncomp, &MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE);
                IMFMediaType_SetUINT32(pTypeUncomp, &MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);

                hr = IMFSourceReader_SetCurrentMediaType(pReader, MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, pTypeUncomp);
                if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) printf("NOT AN MPEG1 STREAM!\n");
            }
        }
    }
    
    SAFERELEASE(&pAttr);
}
```